# Spring Expression Directly access map keys in Selection

Tags: spring, spring-el

Consider that I have parsed a JSON String to a `Map<String, Object>`, which is arbitrarily nested

My JSON looks like:

```
{
  "root": [
   {"k":"v1"},
   {"k":"v2"}
  ]
}
```

I tried the expression `root.?[k == 'v1']`, however received the following error:

```
EL1008E: Property or field 'k' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' - maybe not public?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The evaluation context needs a `MapAccessor`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String json = "{\n" +
            "  \"root\": [\n" +
            "   {\"k\":\"v1\"},\n" +
            "   {\"k\":\"v2\"}\n" +
            "  ]\n" +
            "}";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Object root = mapper.readValue(json, Object.class);
    Expression expression = new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("root.?[k == 'v1']");
    StandardEvaluationContext ctx = new StandardEvaluationContext();
    ctx.addPropertyAccessor(new MapAccessor());
    System.out.println(expression.getValue(ctx, root));
}
```

result:

```
[{k=v1}]
```

Without a `MapAccessor`, you need

```
"['root'].?[['k'] == 'v1']"
```

A `MapAccessor` will only work with map keys that don't contain periods.